# Is it possible to prove that every discrete topology is an order topology without the axiom of choice?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

We can prove that every discrete topology is an order topology with the axiom of choice:

> Say X is a topological space with the discrete topology. By the the axiom of choice, every set can be well-ordered, so X can be viewed as an ordinal. Then shift every limit ordinal in X to its successor and the other ordinals in X accordingly, then the newly-arranged X has an order topology that is discrete.

However, the above process makes use of the AC. I wonder if we can prove that every discrete topology is an order topology without the axiom of choice.

Comment: A weaker question: in ZF can we prove "every set can be totally ordered"?  I seem to recall the answer is "no".

Answer (score 6):

If I’m reading your proof right, I don’t think it’s correct. You seem to be saying to “shift everything up by one”, a starting from each limit ordinal. Inasmuch as this mental operation makes sense, it does not seem to actually change the ordering. You can’t just “shift $\omega$ up to $\omega+1$” and erase the fact that it’s a limit point… it has exactly the same predecessors as it did before.

Instead, what you can do is re-order each segment of type $\omega$ to be of type $\mathbb Z$. More specifically, for each limit ordinal $\alpha$, reorder $\{\alpha,\alpha+1,\alpha+2,\ldots\}$ to be of type $\mathbb Z$. (If your well-ordering has successor type, will have some finite leftovers at the end that can be easily tucked away in the previous segment.) With this reordering, every element has a direct successor and predecessor, so the order topology is discrete.

A bit more transparently, for any ordinal $\alpha$, $\alpha\times \mathbb Z$, with the dictionary order is a discrete order with cardinality $|\alpha|$ if $\alpha$ is infinite. So under AC, any infinite set is equinumerous with some initial ordinal, and thus can be ordered discretely.

Finally, as remarked in the comments by GEdgar, ZF cannot even prove every set has a linear order (e.g. amorphous sets can’t be linearly ordered), so certainly can’t prove every set has a discrete linear order.

Comment: Note that all the last construction needs about $\alpha$ is that it can be totally ordered.  So you only need choice to say that every set can be totally ordered and that $|X\times\mathbb{Z}|=|X|$ for any infinite set $X$.  I suspect this is strictly weaker than full AC.

Comment: Excellent! But what might be a sufficient condition/axiom for the proof to be valid,  which is weaker than the AC?

Comment: @Michael Like Eric says in the comment above, for this proof, the only thing you need in surplus of "every set can be linearly ordered" is that $\mathfrak a\cdot \aleph_0=\mathfrak a$ for every infinite cardinal $\mathfrak a$ (or equivalently, for any infinite cardinal $\mathfrak a,$ $\mathfrak a = 2\mathfrak a$). This combination is strictly in between "every set can be linearly ordered" and full AC. Not sure it is optimal though.

Comment: @Michael To avoid confusion, I should clarify that my previous comment contains three non-trivial claims given without proof. 1) "or equivalently..." 2) the combo is strictly stronger than "every set can be linearly ordered" 3) the combo is strictly weaker than AC. Claim 1 is not too hard. Claim 2 is witnessed by the standard Cohen model of ZF, though the proof that every set can be linearly ordered there came a bit later and isn't easy ( see 5.5 of Jech's AC book). Sageev constructed a model and proved it witnessed claim 3 in the early 70s. I haven't ever attempted to understand it.

Answer (score -1):

Answer may depend of your definition of order topology.

---

**Definition variant 1:**

> For partially ordered set $(X, \leq)$ we define order topology as one generated by subbase consisting of *intervals*, that is sets of the form $(a, b)$, $[m, b)$, $(a, M]$ and $[m, M]$ where $a,b\in X$ are arbitrary, $m$ is arbitrary minimal and $M$ is arbitrary maximal. Recall: $[a, b) = \{x\in X : a \leq x < b \}$ etc.

Now given arbitrary descrete topological space $(X, \tau)$ we can define partial order by $a\leq b \iff a = b$. Since every element is maximal and minimal, every set $[x, x] = \{x\}$ is open.

---

**Definition variant 2:**

> For partially ordered set $(X, \leq)$ we define order topology as one generated by subbase consisting of *rays*, that is sets on the form $\{x\in X: x < b\}$ and $\{x \in X: a < x\}$ where $a,b \in X$ are arbitrary.

In that case I don't think it is possible, but I don't have any proof.

---

Note that for linear orders those definitions are actually the same.